# mongoTemplate is not able to find collection and throws exception

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

root-context.xml:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="localhost" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="meraComputer" mongo-ref="mongo" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDaoImpl" class="net.meraComputer.spring.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="mongoTemplate" ref="mongoTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

UserDaoImpl:

```
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Required
public void setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
}

@Override
public void saveUser(UserAccount user) {
    if(mongoTemplate.collectionExists("userAccount")) {
        mongoTemplate.save(user);
    }else {
        mongoTemplate.createCollection("userAccount");
        mongoTemplate.save(user);
    }
}
```

I have userAccount collection already created while saving the first UserAccount.

```
db.userAccount.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("568781929a0085d703e45e0e"),
"_class" : "net.meraComputer.spring.model.UserAccount",
"username" : "Test",
"password" : "$2a$10$XrDNeBw0vKTr0zEXVVLMy.N2L4wEzJ/C1lBAuvRQB6YC6EMFr3ws6",
"firstname" : "Test",
"lastname" : "Test",
"userRole" : [ ],
"roles" : [
    DBRef("role", "ADMIN")
]
```

But when I try to resister another user it simply return false `mongoTemplate.collectionExists("userAccount")` here and when it goes to the save part it throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: command failed [create]: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "collection already exists" , "code" : 48}; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [create]: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "collection already exists" , "code" : 48}
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:78)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1800)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:388)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doCreateCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1413)
```

I have tried:

```
mongoTemplate.getCollectionNames() - no result.
mongoTemplate.collectionExists(UserAccount.class) - false
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing my dependency to the following solved my problem :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and it was related to the spring framework versions. I updated to use the latest versions and the problem when away.